# How to write labels with varying significant figures/decimal places?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, labeling, vb

I have results that range from ex. 113,009 down to 0.00495 - Can someone recommend a way to write/construct a label expression for the following in ArcMap:

•   If less than 1, use 2 decimal places (or three if absolutely necessary to show the first non-zero value) 
•   From 1 to 10, use 1 decimal place
•   If 10 or greater, use no decimal places

Or a way to quickly generate a new text column/field which adheres to the above?

Comment: Certainly, sorry about that...done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the code below as the label expression for your feature in ArcMap. Set the parser to Python and check the Advanced box. Change [yourField] to the field containing the values you want to label.

```
def FindLabel([yourField]):
    if [yourField] is not None:
        value = float([yourField])
        if value < 1:
            return round(value, 3)
        elif 1 <= value < 10:
            return round(value, 1)
        else:
            return round(value, 0)
    else:
        return None
```

I put the values that are less than one to three decimal places, but change it to two if you want.

Comment: Please do not "correct" the elif line here because the `elif 1 <= value < 10:`syntax is quite valid and, I think, more pythonic than a non-author edit which was made to it and approved.

Comment: @PolyGeo yes my bad and I apologize. I saw it and the quick reaction from the programmer in me changed it so that it made sense to someone reading it. Both work. For the record `pythonic` at times is synonymous with esoteric which generally is not good for reusable code.

Comment: @JamesSLC Yeah, well, you know, that's just, like, your opinion, man.

Comment: @ian I agree. No worries/disrespect though, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @JamesSLC No I didn't think that. I just wanted to use a quote from The Big Lebowski :)